# Waffle iron with changeable plates for butter galettes

Tags: equipment, waffle

I'm looking for a recommendation for a waffle iron with interchangeable plates for butter [galettes](http://www.acemal.com/site/en/waffle-galette-waffles-butter-gaufre-beurre.html).

I have one but it's over 30 years old, falling apart and runs off 220V to boot.
Are there any replacements? I cannot find any, anywhere.

Comment: Why does it need interchangeable plates?

Comment: So I can make waffles most of the time and Galettes around new years :-)

Comment: Ah, you mean that they need a different shape? I had thought that you want to change the same shape during cooking, and wondered what the purpose would be. It is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's hard to find this online. You better check your kitchen appliance store.

I did find [this](http://r.twenga.nl/g3.php?pg=VDs4ODI1NTgyNTcxNDU3MTc4MjEyOzIwMTIwMzE7aHR0cDovL2RvbWV0aWMuZm90b3ZpZGVvaW1wb3J0Lm5sL3Byb2R1Y3RfaW5mby5waHA/cHJvZHVjdHNfaWQ9NDI2MTc7ZTM3NWRiMGU3ZWQzZGUyMDExYTc4OTc2ZWM1ZGQwNWI=) that is compatible with [these](http://r.twenga.nl/g3.php?pg=VDszNzI1MTI5MzMwNzc1MDEyNjQ1OzI3NTAyOTE7aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vbmRlcmRlbGVud2Vic2hvcC5iZS9zZXQtaGFydGplc3BsYXRlbi13YWZlbGlqemVyLWZyaWZyaS00OTQ1Lmh0bWw7ZTM3NWRiMGU3ZWQzZGUyMDExYTc4OTc2ZWM1ZGQwNWI=) plates, but I don't think they'll ship to where you live. Plus they are quite expensive and I have no idea about their quality.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the waffle iron as is and just not close it, I would think.  Though I am also not able to find a replacement, except through alibaba.

**Edit based on apparent flag and mod comment:**

All a special galette plate will provide is the shape.  You can still make the batter, spoon a couple of tablespoons onto a hot waffle iron and yield exactly the same thing, albeit in a different shape.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question, and it picked a flag. Please elaborate what you mean, or I will delete it as "not an answer"

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find a new iron they are available.  Try Verkinderen belgian cookie iron,     they are available, to the best of my knowledge, at DeRonne Hardware store.  Check their website under specialty items.

Comment: Does this iron include changeable plates for making butter galettes?